# PHP How to get a boolean average of an array

Tags: php, arrays, boolean

EDIT2: This goes to the top for a reason. This question is asked wrong, but I won´t change the title, since maybe other people are caught in this misstake. I am NOT looking for an "average" - I merely want to exit with the first "false" in an array.
My though to this questions were quite twisted - therefore I asked the wrong question.
Anyway: As stated, I won´t change the question itself.

What I want to do is basically calculate something like a boolean average of an array. I know about booleans and that they are not meant to be something with an average, but please read on to see what I am doing.

My array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    true,
    false,
    true,
    true
);
```

I now want to get an AND-operation done on this array to see, if everything in there is true or if a subfunction returned false. This is basically a list of results from different subfunctions.

This specific example then should return false, because $array[1] is false.

EDIT:

What I am looking for is a builtin PHP-function which seems not to exists. A custom implementation has the advantage to exit the iteration over this array in comparison to in_array() which might not do this.

Can you help me out, stackoverflow?

Comment: check out my code, that would work for you I think :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Come on, it would appear you didn't even try:

```
function checkArray(array $in)
{
    foreach ($in as $bool)
    {
        if (!$bool)//replace with type&value checking if that's what you're after
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
var_dump(checkArray(array(true, false, true, true)));//false
var_dump(checkArray(array(true, true)));//true
```

There are, of course, a bunch of alternative ways to do what you want/need, depending on what the actual data will look like. If it's all booleans:

```
if (array_sum($array) != count($array))
{//true == 1, array_sum(array(true, true)) == count(array(true, true)) == 2
    echo 'array contains false, or non-boolean values, like 123';
}
//for a real average:
$avg = round(array_sum($array)/count($array));
```

The latter will yield `1` if 50%>= of the values in the array are `true`, and 0 otherwise. It's then a simple matter of casting that value to a boolean to get the *"average bool value"*:

```
$avg = (bool) round(
    array_sum($array)/count($array)
);
```

or, for example:

```
$valsAsKey = array_flip(
    array_map(
        'intval',//make ints
        $array
    )
);
if (isset($valsAsKey[0]))
{//(int) false === 0
    echo 'False in array';
}
```

Though these approaches don't use iteration *explicitly*, they do iterate the array data implicitly. A quick test did show that the simple `foreach` outperformed the other approaches here.

Comment: I forgot to state, that I would dislike an iterative approach, since the array could grow quite big. Sorry for that :/

Comment: @PeterUkena: At some point, if you want to find something in an array, you'll have to iterate it. If you use `in_array`, you don't _see_ the loop (as in: you don't write one yourself), but `in_array` does iterate the data, regardless. The advantage of iterating yourself is that you can return inside the loop, as soon as you find a non-true value, which avoids traversing the array in its entirety

Comment: I know that as well. Gosh, I need some coffee - sorry for beeing so unclear and stupid. :D To put it this way: There seems not to be a builtin PHP-function that does, what I described. I can use an own implementation or in_array() which both is  kind of okay for my needs.  I guess, the point that I can cancel the interation in an own implementation is the key here. Thanks for clearing that up. :)

Comment: Well, the big difference here is, If I create a function, I can end the iteration after the first false - which is what I should do. Otherwise I may get performance issues. By the way, I think its kind of insecure to rely on true and false beeing evaluated to 1 and 0 in arithmetics, isn´t it?

Comment: You can put my whole code into a function aswlel, thats not a problem actually. What kind of insecure do you mean?

Comment: Actually, true MEANS 1 and false MEANS 0 in binary.

Comment: Well, true and false are booleans, which are interpreted or represented as 1 and 0 in our number-system. One should calculate with digits and not with booleans. They do not have numeric values at all, just a representation as numeric values. Better to use the === operator to check for real booleans like in the code above - at least in my opinion.

Comment: @PeterUkena: That's why I added the `type-and-value checking` comment in my answer :)

Comment: Well thats not a must, though.

Comment: You just have to be safe, that you don't get other values, like random integers. Then its fine because you KNOW that you are working with booleans.

Comment: @Xatenev: Read my answer, I mention those things throughout: I recommend type & value checks _"if required"_, and suggest alternatives _"Depending on what the actual data will look like"_, and proceed to give an example _"if it's all booleans"_

Comment: Well my comment was going to Peter Ukena though. About insecurity 'n so on, in my code.

Comment: The insecurity I was talking about totally refers to my point of view on this particular problem. I need to be on a safer side and this code covers it better for my needs. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in%5farray):

```
$array = array(
    true,
    false,
    true,
    true
);

echo in_array(false, $array);
```

If one of the elements is false, it will return `false` otherwise it returns `true`.

**Update**: [`in_array`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP%5f5%5f3/ext/standard/array.c#1244), [returns out of the loop](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP%5f5%5f3/ext/standard/array.c#1219) as soon as the searched value is matched.  The worst case I suppose is when you have a single `false` at the end of the searched array.  The linked source are for PHP 5.3.

As far as strict checking is concerned, you can do so passing in the third parameter to `in_array`:

```
echo in_array(false, $array, true);
```

Comment: Is in_array fast enough for big arrays? :)

Comment: What, if there are 10 falses, and 2 trues. Then this will return true, instead of false.
in_array(false,$array)

Comment: Thats a point. As well as the argument in the marked answer - both things led me to use an own implementation to cancel the iteration at any point I want. Thanks for this answer as well. :)

Comment: @Xatenev, I understood from the question description that the OP was looking to search for `false` in an array.  You're right the question, however asks to find average!

Comment: @PeterUkena, `in_array` should exit out of the loop as soon as the searched element is found.  Please see the updated answer for more on this.  Also, you can pass the third parameter `$strict = true` to include type checking as well, as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, that is it. Though I asked the wrong question as pointed out in the updated question. ;) Thanks for the hint with the strict-parameter, but I ended up using a custom implementation to be a little more flexible in my project here. Thanks a lot still! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried around a lot, until i came to this final result.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$array = array();

$array[] = true;
$array[] = false;
$array[] = false;
$array[] = true;
$array[] = false;
var_dump($array);



if((count($array)/2) <= array_sum($array)){
    echo "true";

    // return true
} else {
    echo "false";

    // return false
}
?>
```

it counts the elements of the array, and compares it with the COUNTED trues (array_sum($array)). Then it returns true or false, dependent on result.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the array and set a result to false if any vals are false;

```
$result = true;
foreach ($array as $v) {
  if ($v===false) $result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter` without callback. In this case all entries of array equal to `false` will be removed.

```
if (count(array_filter($array)) == count($array)) echo 'TRUE';
```